# Button click firing twice

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have built an outlook addin, and I wanted to add on feature to it, the problem I'm having the new button I added it firing twice on click - there is no duplicate button name or duplicate event listener in taskpane.js or taskpane.html

here is the code snippet for the button:

```
    document.getElementById("generate-email-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
      var recipientType = document.getElementById("new-email-recipient-type").value;
      var emailType = document.getElementById("email-type").value;
      var emailContent = document.getElementById("email-content").value;
      var emailTone1 = document.getElementById("emailTone1").value;
      var emailTone2 = document.getElementById("emailTone2").value;
      
      generateSuggestedEmail(recipientType, emailType, emailContent, emailTone1, emailTone2);
    });
```

The console tells me that both taskpane.js and the js file made by the webpack are registering the click

```
d47f4b55d6e75be28dfc.js:797 generateSuggestedEmail called
taskpane.js:721 generateSuggestedEmail called
```

but no other function or button gets called twice like that. I can't find the root cause of this, wondering if any of you have any experience with this or have a workaround?

What I'm expecting to happen is the button click only registers once. I have tried finding the duplicate event listener there is none that I create - there obviously is one in d47f4b55d6e75be28dfc.js but that is created by the webpack from my code, so there is no way to remove that without removing it from my code.

Comment: Probably an issue with event bubbling https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: I assume `taskpane.js` is your source and `d47...js` is the bundled version. You should be only including the latter in your Outlook app. From the console messages it looks like you're including both.

Comment: How does your `webpack.config.js` look like?

Comment: Is there a chance the add-in was sideloaded twice with different files referenced?

Comment: Yes d47...js is my bundled version. I haven't purposely added them both to the dist folder, that could be the webpacks doing, though I don't see any information in the webpack.config.js that would indicate that this was a desired/not desired outcome.

Comment: No the add-in hasn't been sideloaded twice. I have checked that and removed and readded the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include both files to the output folder. Most probably you have webpack improperly configured to include them both to the `dist` folder. I'd suggest clearing the dist folder and building the solution anew. You need to include only one *.js file to the `dist` folder.

Also to remove an add-in that you've previously sideloaded on Windows, Mac, or iOS, you need to clear the Office cache on your computer. Additionally, if you make changes to your add-in's manifest (for example, update file names of icons or text of add-in commands), you should clear the Office cache and then re-sideload the add-in using an updated manifest. Doing so allows Office to render the add-in as it's described by the updated manifest. See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information.

Comment: I'm not including both files, but both are being added to the dist folder with each build, I assume that must be how the webpack is configured, but I don't see that as part of the webpack config either.

Comment: Where is your webpack.config.js file?