Word runs both my source js file and the webpacked file, making all functions run twice (Office JS Yeoman)
Both taskpane.js and a packed version of the same file (75af049aa831360ba2a0.js) are running at the same time in my Office JS Add-in. I only want my file/functions to be run once.
Here is my webpack.config.js:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"],
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76507455/button-click-firing-twice\
Others in the above question have suggested changing webpack.config.js, but have not said in what way, and from reading docs and other questions i cannot find what is causing this in my code.
Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks
-zach

In webpack.config.js, commenting out all the variables in entry (polyfill,taskpane,commands) stopped them from being included and packed, removing the duplicate functions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had this same issue, the root issue for me was I had unnecessarily linked the taskpane.js file in taskpane.html
